# Codename one Calendar project issue

Tags: java, android, codenameone, wiki, android-calendar

I am working on my Codename one calendar project where I have included Calendar not from Codename one API, but created a customized calendar by own So, when I am adding day buttons to the calendar using for loop then it will be added successfully, But it will start from first day that is from Sunday, But the actual Calendar month not starting from Sunday so how can I add it from that respected actual day and also I want that when the next month starting the day button will carry on their respective chain from previous month to next month for instance, If current month end on wednesday so the next month's first day will start from thursday and so on. So anyone know how to achieve this scenario?

**Below are my application screenshot and their respected code:-**

[image]

```
public class PivDisplayCalendar extends Container {
    PivEventCalendar EventObject = new PivEventCalendar();
    PivCalendarModel ModelObject = new PivCalendarModel();
    PivCalendarDatabase DatabaseObject = new PivCalendarDatabase();
    int length =31;
     private ComboBox year;
     private static final String[] DAYS = {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
     private static final String[] LABELS = {"Su", "M", "Tu", "W", "Th", "F", "Sa"};
     private static final String[] MONTHS = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
     private static final int[] YEARS = {2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027};
     public int i = 1, j=0;
     public Date value = new Date();
     public Object metaData;

     private ArrayList<Button> allButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();
     //Button newButton = new Button("");

    public PivDisplayCalendar(){
        super(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
            Log.p("Calendar invoked");
            Container calendarTitle = new Container(new BorderLayout(BorderLayout.CENTER_BEHAVIOR_CENTER));
            Container title = new Container(new GridLayout(1,7));
            Container days = new Container(new GridLayout(6, 7));
            Container calendarTitleCopy = new Container(new GridLayout(1, 1));
                calendarTitleCopy.setUIID("CalendarTitleCopy");
            this.addComponent(calendarTitleCopy);
            this.addComponent(title);
            this.addComponent(days);


            Button prevMonth = new Button("<");
            Button nextMonth = new Button(">");
            Label month = new Label(MONTHS[0]);
            Label yearLabel = new Label( "2017");
            calendarTitle.add(BorderLayout.WEST, prevMonth);
            Container TitleLabel = FlowLayout.encloseIn(month,yearLabel);
            calendarTitle.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, TitleLabel);
            calendarTitle.add(BorderLayout.EAST, nextMonth);
            calendarTitleCopy.add(calendarTitle);
            Button dayButton= new Button();




           if(UIManager.getInstance().isThemeConstant("calTitleDayStyleBool", false)) {
                title.setUIID("CalendarTitleArea");
                days.setUIID("CalendarDayArea");
            }
            for (int iter = 0; iter < DAYS.length; iter++) {
                title.addComponent(createDayTitle(iter));
            }
            for (int iter = 1; iter < length; iter++) {
               dayButton = new Button(""+iter);
              /* Log.p("Getting data from Model class");
               Log.p(""+DatabaseObject.ModelObject.getEventData()); */
                    dayButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                            Log.p("Action event triggered");
                            Picker datePicker = new Picker();

                            try{
                                Display.getInstance().showNativePicker(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,PivDisplayCalendar.this, value, metaData);
                                Storage.getInstance().writeObject("Date", value);
                                ModelObject.setEventDate(value);

                            }catch(Exception e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }


                            //Button b1 = (Button)(evt.getActualComponent());
                            //Log.p( b1.getText() );
                        }
                    });

               allButtons.add(dayButton);
                days.addComponent(dayButton);
                if (iter <= 7) {
                    dayButton.setNextFocusUp(year);
                }
            }    

            nextMonth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                month.setText(MONTHS[i]);
                yearLabel.setText(""+YEARS[j]);
                if((i<MONTHS.length-1)){
                    i++;
                }
                else{
                    i=0;
                    j++;
                }
            }
        });

            prevMonth.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            month.setText(MONTHS[i]);
            yearLabel.setText(""+YEARS[j]);
            if((i<MONTHS.length+1)){
                i--;
            }
            else{
                i=0;
                j--;
            }
        }
   });

    }

     protected Label createDayTitle(int day) {
        String value = getUIManager().localize("Calendar" + DAYS[day], LABELS[day]);
        Label dayh = new Label(value, "Label");
        dayh.setEndsWith3Points(false);
        dayh.setTickerEnabled(false);
        return dayh;
    }



}
```

Comment: Do you mean how do you know if in the current locale the first day of the week is Sunday or Monday? 
If so we don't currently have an API for that but probably need one in `L10NManager`